# Vim Ex mode regex: How to do case-aware word swap

Tags: regex, vim

A regular obstacle I meet is wanting to replace all occurrences a word with its replacement, but also its alternate-cased variants. I want to do this in a single command. Example:

Original:
`Bananas? Ew, I don't like bananas.`

Nifty regex:
`:%s/Something/Clever/g`

Result:
`Grapes? Ew, I don't like grapes.`

Is there any way to perform this replacement in a neat way that's faster than doing both the following commands?
`:%s/Bananas/Grapes/g`
`:%s/bananas/grapes/g`

Comment: Try https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several plugins that allow this:

- [SmartCase](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1359):

```
:%s/bananas/\=SmartCase("grapes")/ig
```

- [my SmartCase fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SmartCase):

```
:%SmartCase/bananas/grapes/g
```

- [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish):

```
:%Subvert/{b,B}ananas/{g,G}rapes/g
```

Comment: [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) has an screencast about Abolish.vim's `:Subvert` command: [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)

Answer (score 1):

You also have `:SubstituteCase` from [keepcase.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6)

```
:SubstituteCase#\ctoto\(Titi\)tata#\1Tutu#g

     totoTitiTata -> titiTutu
     TotoTitiTata -> TitiTutu
     tototititata -> tititutu
     tototitiTata -> titiTutu
     TototitiTata -> TitiTutu
```

Answer (score 0):

If ignorecase is set:

```
:s/bananas/Grapres/|s//grapes
```

But this is more a trick (// stands for the previous searched pattern, i.e. bananas) than a solution, I'd rather use a plugin as others suggested.